# get record having a combination of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my sample table

```
CREATE TABLE agentskills 
( 
    id          INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
    skilluserid INT, 
    skillid     INT NOT NULL, 
    skilltypeid INT, 
    priority    INT DEFAULT 0 
)
```

these are my sample data

```
INSERT INTO AGENTSKILLS (skilluserid , skillid, SKILLTYPEID,priority ) VALUES (1,21,1,1)
INSERT INTO AGENTSKILLS (skilluserid , skillid, SKILLTYPEID,priority ) VALUES (1,22,1,1)

INSERT INTO AGENTSKILLS (skilluserid , skillid, SKILLTYPEID,priority ) VALUES (2,23,1,1)
INSERT INTO AGENTSKILLS (skilluserid , skillid, SKILLTYPEID,priority ) VALUES (2,24,1,1)

INSERT INTO AGENTSKILLS (skilluserid , skillid, SKILLTYPEID,priority ) VALUES (3,21,1,1)
INSERT INTO AGENTSKILLS (skilluserid , skillid, SKILLTYPEID,priority ) VALUES (3,22,1,1)
```

Here, 'skilluserid' is the id of user having the skill 'skillid'

how can i fetch users/skilluserid having a combination of skillid ?

eg : get user(s) having skillid 21 and 22 or 22 and 21 or 21,22,23. any combination having 21 and 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select skilluserid
from agentskills
where skillid in (21, 22)
group by skilluserid
having count(distinct skillid) = 2;  -- "2" = size of list in where clause
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use exist if you need all column in selection

```
select t1.* from agentskills t1
where  exists ( select 1 from agentskills t2 where t1.skilluserid=t2.skilluserid
                 and skillid in (21, 22) 
                 having count(distinct skillid) = 2
            ) and skillid in (21, 22)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use intersect,

```
select skilluserid
from agentskills 
where skillid =21

INTERSECT

select skilluserid
from agentskills 
where skillid =22
```

Comment: works when 2 skills has to be matched.  if i try to match 21,22 and 23 it fails. but i am happy to learn INTERSECT. I could use it elsewhere to make a few tasks easier. thanks !